# How to pick multiple images from device?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

If i create a simple project:

```
ionic start MyApp
```

And add the `ImagePicker` plugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git -save
```

And simply copy [this example www folder](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/multiimageselect/multiimageselect3) into the project and do:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

Everything is working fine. I can pick multiple images as intended without getting any errors.

So far so good. Now i tried to include that into my project so i added the `ImagePicker` plugin. Now this is my plugin list:

```
ionic plugin ls
com.synconset.imagepicker 1.0.6 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 1.1.0 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

I created a new module:

```
angular.module('App.ImageSelect', [])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.imageSelect', {
        url: "/products/prints/pola/imageSelect",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "modules/products/prints/pola/imageSelect/imageSelect.html",
                controller: 'ImageSelectController'
            }
        }
    });
})

.controller('ImageSelectController', function ($scope, $cordovaImagePicker) {
    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.selectImages = function () {
        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(
            function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);

                    $scope.images.push(results[i]);
                }

                if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

As you can see it is EXACTLY the SAME controller which i copied from [here](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/multiimageselect/multiimageselect3) which worked on the simple test project.

For any suspect reason this is NOT working. I always get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined
```

So what's the point of that? Im using EXACT the same code in both projects. In one everything is working and in the other nothing is working. I tried all the examples described [here](http://mr-cordova.blogspot.de/2015/03/selecting-multiple-images-in.html) but its always the same.

Comment: Have you given the app access to the camera in manifest?

Comment: Since version 3.0 you never need to edit that manually. it all gets generated automatically

Comment: Did you add `cordova-imagePicker` plugin? If yes, remove and reinstall it again. I just checked my test app and plugin works fine on iOS, can pickup any 5 images. Checking in Android...

Comment: It did not help. Unfortunately

Comment: Update: Yes, works in Android too.

Comment: I'm using this plugin com.synconset.imagepicker 1.0.6 "ImagePicker"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your project and your index.html is missing  `cordova.js` . So none of your plugins are getting loaded or initialized.
Just add the below line in you index.html below where you load ng-cordova.js.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow... it was the most obvious and i did not see it after 3 days. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

On you example your are injecting `$cordovaCamera`, however the iconic uses `$cordovaImagePicker`. Also , in your example your using the object `imagePicker` from the `window` object. I don't the `window` object is what you want.

Try injecting the correct dependency `$cordovaImagePicker` and use the method  `$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures` from it instead.

Comment: @Mulgard: ThiagoPXP is right. Try using ngCordova and inject `$cordovaImagePicker` then use `$cordovaImagePicker`. Reference [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/).